Formal way to state that a condition is true for a certain number of elements of a set.
This may be very simple, but I have the following problem: I have a certain logical condition, let us call it $\theta(i)$, with $i \in X$, which can be true or false for the argument $i$. Now I want to formally state that $\theta(i)$ cannot be true for more than one element of the set $X$ (being true for none of the elements of $X$ should also be included). Can anyone help me?

$\left|{i\in X,|,\theta(i)}\right| \le 1$

I suggest a frame change. If you are writing for a human reader and not a software application that checks proofs written in some formal language, accurate words are easier to understand than logical propositions, and just as rigorous. So simply say

$\theta(i)$ is true for at most one element $i \in X$.


There are multiple ways to state this, but one that works well in constructive mathematics is to say that the subset of $X$ on the elements which satisfy $\theta$ is a mere proposition, in the sense that any two of its elements are equal:
$$\forall i, j \in X. \theta(i) \land \theta(j) \to i = j$$
or equivalently
$$\forall i, j \in \{x \in X \mid \theta(x)\}. i = j$$

Just for interpretation: this means that $\theta(i)$ can only be true for two elements of $X$ if the two elements are equal, right?

Yeah, or rather the meaning of that sentence is what I wrote :)

@zinsinho: ... Or in other words, it's not two elements, it's one single element.

For simplicity, how about stating there is not a distinct $i$ and $j$ such that $\theta$ is true for both, i.e.:
$$\not\exists i, j \in X, i \not = j : \theta(i) \land \theta(j)$$

In the general case if $Y$ is your cardinal you just want $X \cap\theta$ in bijection with $Y$, because bijection is 'is a certain number' for cardinals.
You can expand each bit to however formal you want it but I'd stop there, because expressing the existence of a bijection in terms of $\in$ and $\mathcal{P}$ is an exercise you only need to do once.
